# What css attribute is more important?

Tags: css

What is more important: putting the style in the `<div style="color: black !important">`
or using a class and defining a value `!important`?

What is more important:

```
border-color: black !important;
border-right-color: transparent !important;
```

Will the right border be transparent now, or will it be black?

Comment: Where is your test case? It probably would answer your question.

Comment: read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and this: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade

Comment: @NicoO And thank you too those 2 really help alot.

Comment: The *what* is so trivial to test it probably would have been faster to test it than to write this question (these *two* questions), unless you are asking *why* it works the way it does.

Comment: @user3466437 well my last line was Please explain why? but someon edited it out.

Comment: @StijnBernards Dammit. That was me. Sorry. You should put it back in.

Comment: @user3466437 haha okay no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, left,top and bottom borders will be black. But, the border right will be transparent. Depends of the order of the commands. Because, both they have the same level of priority.

Comment: Inline css, is less important than class !important. But, !important inside of style is more important then everything.

But, is not to beautiful

Answer (score 1):

all sides of border except the right one will be black. right one will be transparent, as per your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: If you mark as important in a class and then try to put a style for the same property, WON'T be applied.

Q2: It depends on the order that you put this on your file. They have the same priority. The latest one, will be the one that will be applied

Answer (score 1):

!important, is used to determine priority.

```
.div {border:1px solid #ccc}
.div2 {border:2px solid #fff !important} //priority
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question in any way. It compares two border shorthand declarations, but not a border-color with a border-right-color.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link. The only "important" for informational purposes I put it.

Comment: I'm talking about your entire answer, not just the link.

Answer (score 0):

1. <strike>Obviously, something is missing between "... style in the" and "or using ...". Use backticks for inline code snippets.</strike>
2. Sinse both styles are used with `!important`, their strength is calculated according to their [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), that are also equal. Thus, first applies, then the following is ovverriding first. Finally, we have top, left, bottom borders black, and right is transparent. See http://jsfiddle.net/hjrvue13/

UPD: I see you edited your question.

Inline style is more important than class, if class have directive !important, class is more important. If both inline and class have !important, again inline style is more important.

Answer (score -2):

style has hieher Specificity then a class.

you could see all about Specificity here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

I think the answer to question 2, is what comes latest in the css.